# How to connect to wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless

I'dont have the option in my ubuntu desktop to connect to wifi. I have never connected internet in ubuntu before. Do I need to install drivers or something like that. If yes how can I do it?

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device          [14e4:05e2]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if network-manager is install.

terminal : sudo apt-get install network-manager.

You should check the infos about your wireless card too.

terminal : lspci

And installing the proper drivers.

Comment: how do I install network manager or drivers without connecting to internet. is there a way to download it in Windows and then transfer and install it in ubuntu.

Comment: Did you run sudo apt-get install network-manager to check if it's already installed ? If's a driver problem you can download them in windows then copy them on ubuntu.

Comment: network manager is already installed. how to install drivers manually